# JavaScript help to compare arrays and get two new arrays with differently formatted and spacers added as needed

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I am creating an Angular app in which I need help with TypeScript/JavaScript.

**I have two string arrays.**

| Array1 | Array2 |
| --- | --- |
| 3/30/2023 | 3/30/2023 |
| 3/31/2023 | 4/14/2023 |
| 4/14/2023 | 6/30/2023 |
| 4/25/2023 | 7/31/2023 |
| 6/30/2023 |  |

I am trying to compare Array1 and Array2 and creating two new string arrays Array3 and Array4.

**While creating Array3 and Array4:**

If Array1 and Array2 have same values then insert to Array3 and Array4, respectively.

If Array1 has '3/31/2023' and that is not in Array2 then insert '3/31/2030' in Array3 and a blank string in Array4, and vice versa.

At the end Array3 and Array4 will have same length and they can be displayed in a table side by side.

| Array3 | Array4 |
| --- | --- |
| 3/30/2023 | 3/30/2023 |
| 3/31/2023 | "" |
| 4/14/2023 | 4/14/2023 |
| 4/25/2023 | "" |
| 6/30/2023 | 6/30/2023 |
| "" | 7/31/2023 |

FYI: Array1 and Array2 can be of any length including empty array for one or for both

I like to have solution using RxJS, however, not a must. Any help will
be great on this.

Thanks very much

---

My attempts:

I tried solution using **for loops and if statements**. It works for most of the time, however, not for all situations.

In addition, my code is long with multiple for and if statements. I am preferably looking for code in rxjs, however, a JavaScript code is great as well.

**Code:**

//Compare two arrays... when an element is missing in the first array then insert blank
**private addBlankToMissingEelement2(array1, array2): Array** {

```
//Deep clone to avoid array mutation
let arrTemp1 = Object.assign([], array1)
let arrTemp2 = Object.assign([], array2)

var arrTemp1Length = arrTemp1.length;
var arrTemp2Length = arrTemp2.length;
let arr1FirstElement = arrTemp1[0];

if (arrTemp1Length === 0 || arrTemp2Length === 0)
  return array1;

for (let i = 0; i < arrTemp1Length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < arrTemp2Length; j++) {
    if (arrTemp1[i] == '' || arrTemp2[j] == '' || arrTemp1[i] == undefined || arrTemp2[j] == undefined) {
      break;
    }
    else if (arrTemp1[i] == arrTemp2[j]) {
      break;
    }
    else if (i == 0 && arr1FirstElement > arrTemp2[j]) { //Add blank to first array at the begining as many times as needed
      array1.unshift('');
      arrTemp1Length++;
    }
    else if (arrTemp1[i] != arrTemp2[j] && arrTemp1[i] < arrTemp2[j + 1]) {
      console.log("In last --- " + " [" + i + ", " + j + "] --- " + " --- " + arrTemp1[i] + " --- " + arrTemp2[j] + arrTemp2[j + 1]);
      array2.splice(j + 1, 0, '');
      arrTemp2Length++;
      break;
    }

  }
}

return array1;
```

}

Comment: If you want any help I would suggest you to improve your question. Give meaningful names to your variables. Mark the code sections with the right markup. Reduce your problem to the bare minimum: for example, converting dates to string can be done beforehand, your question should focus only on the string array comparison. Show what you tried until now. Also, this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

In your solution, you use a nested loop, where you go through the second array for each element of the first. But you need to go through both arrays at the same time.

Here is a pretty straight-forward way of solving it by keeping an index for each array, and then checking which value comes next:

```js
const array1 = [
  "12/12/2023",
  "3/30/2023",
  "3/31/2023",
  "4/14/2023",
  "4/25/2023",
  "6/30/2023",
];
const array2 = [
  "1/1/2024",
  "12/12/2023",
  "3/30/2023",
  "4/14/2023",
  "6/30/2023",
  "7/31/2023",
];

function toSortedDateArray(arr){
  return arr.map(s => new Date(s)).sort( (d1, d2) => d1 - d2 )
}

function buildRows(arr1, arr2){
  const dates1 = toSortedDateArray(arr1), dates2 = toSortedDateArray(arr2)
  const column1 = [], column2 = []
  let ix1 = 0, ix2 = 0
  while(ix1 < dates1.length || ix2 < dates2.length){
    const v1 = dates1[ix1], v2 = dates2[ix2]
    const useV1 = (!v2 || v1 - v2 <= 0), useV2 = (!useV1 || v1 - v2 === 0)
    column1.push(useV1 ? v1 : undefined)
    column2.push(useV2 ? v2 : undefined)
    useV1 && ix1++
    useV2 && ix2++
  }
  return [
    column1.map(date => date?.toLocaleDateString("en-US")), 
    column2.map(date => date?.toLocaleDateString("en-US"))
  ]
}

const res = buildRows(array1, array2)
console.log('rowise output:', res[0].map((v1,i) => [v1,res[1][i]]))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Here is a second version, which builds a list of dates first and then checks which column to put each date in. It works with any number of arrays:

```js
const array1 = [
  "12/12/2023",
  "3/30/2023",
  "3/31/2023",
  "4/14/2023",
  "4/25/2023",
  "6/30/2023",
];
const array2 = [
  "1/1/2024",
  "12/12/2023",
  "3/30/2023",
  "4/14/2023",
  "6/30/2023",
  "7/31/2023",
];
const array3 = [
  "4/14/2023",
  "12/12/2023",
  "6/30/2023",
  "3/30/2023",
];

const combine = (...arrays) =>
  // build sorted list of unique dates
  [...new Set(arrays.flat())]
  .map(d => new Date(d))
  .sort((d1, d2) => d1 - d2 )
  .map(d => d.toLocaleDateString("en-US"))
  // build rows
  .map(d => arrays.map(arr => arr.includes(d) ? d : null))
  // transpose to columns
  .reduce(
    (cols, row) => (row.forEach( (v, colIx) => cols[colIx].push(v)), cols), 
    arrays.map(_ => [])
  )

const res =  combine(array1, array2, array3)
console.log('rowise output:', Array.from({length: res[0].length}, (_,i) => res.map(col => col[i])))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this algo

```js
const array1 = [
    "3/30/2023",
    "3/31/2023",
    "4/14/2023",
    "4/25/2023",
    "6/30/2023"
];
const array2 = [
    "3/30/2023",
    "4/14/2023",
    "6/30/2023",
    "7/31/2023"
];
let m=array1.length;
let n=array2.length;
const array3: string[] =[];
const array4: string[] =[];
let i=0,j=0;
for(;i<m||j<n;) {
    if(array1[i]==array2[j]) {
        array3.push(array1[i++]);
        array4.push(array2[j++]);
    }
    else if(array2[j]==undefined || array1[i]<array2[j]) {
        array3.push(array1[i++]);
        array4.push("");
    }
    else if(array1[i]==undefined || array1[i]>array2[j]) {
        array3.push("");
        array4.push(array2[j++]);
    }
}

console.log(array3);
console.log(array4);
```